# "class" field in database

Tags: java, jooq

I have a database which contains table PLAYERS_APPEARANCE where there's field named "Class".

I'm querying with jooq like so

```
PlayersAppearance pp = getCtx().select(PLAYERS_APPEARANCE.RACE,PLAYERS_APPEARANCE.CLASS,PLAYERS_APPEARANCE.GENDER).
    from(PLAYERS_APPEARANCE).where(PLAYERS_APPEARANCE.ID.equal(id)).fetchInto(PlayersAppearance.class).get(0);
```

PlayersAppearance.class is POJO generated by jooq. For Class field it generated **class_** field in java and I access it with **getClass_()** method. class_ is named to avoid conflict with native method getClass(), but it also breaks the database field value somehow

**Problem**

PlayersApperance pa = pa.getClass_() returns NPE

[Debugger image: As you can see in the debugger class_ is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upt9f.png)

Why?

Comment: Every field is null in the debugger screen, even the id. You are not reading that record from the database at all

Comment: I read only 3 fields as shown in the query: race, gender and class. And class field is only one empty

Comment: Activate [jOOQ logging](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/sql-execution/logging/) and see what happens then

Comment: Logging shows normal processing, values are read ok

Comment: Instead of `.fetchInto(PlayersAppearance.class)` that uses reflection try using `.fetchInto(PLAYERS_APPEARANCE)`

Comment: this has worked. how come?

Comment: For the record, [this question was also asked on the jOOQ user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jooq-user/23S69IRSaa0/BpcXApQKAwAJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `fetchInto(Table)` instead of `fetchInto(Class)`:

```
PlayersAppearance pa = ctx
   .select(PLAYERS_APPEARANCE.RACE
         , PLAYERS_APPEARANCE.CLASS
         , PLAYERS_APPEARANCE.GENDER)
   .from(PLAYERS_APPEARANCE)
   .where(PLAYERS_APPEARANCE.ID.eq(id))
   .fetchInto(PLAYERS_APPEARANCE)
```

Maybe the Java generator appended an underscore to the field name, but the [`fetchInto(Class)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.5.x/org/jooq/Record.html#into-java.lang.Class-) API relies on reflection to do its job, and it seems it's not instructed to use `setClass_()` as the setter for the `CLASS` database column.

On the other side, [`fetchInto(Table)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.5.x/org/jooq/Record.html#into-org.jooq.Table-) is always the safest choice because the mapping from database column to field is statically decided at code generation time (you can check it yourself), so no bean/property/whatever happens at runtime that can make the mapping not working.

This may be a bug (or a missing feature) in jOOQ - you should file a ticket and wait for the support team.